# Are scientific laws examples of immaterial things having causal power?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, natural

A scientific law is clearly immaterial. It has no shape nor does it take the form of matter. It is also abstract.

It is considered a mathematical description of the regularities we see in nature, but since nature obeys these laws, doesn’t that mean these laws have causal power? Thus, doesn’t this mean immaterial things have causal power?

Comment: Descriptions are not prescriptions.

Comment: But these descriptions have predictive power. @D.Halsey Why would regularities exist in the first place if they didn’t also have prescriptive power?

Comment: Except if those regularities happen because of the configuration of material things. Just like when you can't put the square peg in the round hole: it is not because of some grand principle of pegs and holes, but simply because it doesn't fit. In that case it's just material things that have causal power, which is also more parcimonious. As @D.Halsey says, what we call scientific laws are just a descriptions of perceived regularities.

Comment: Isn’t that still just a law? @armand A peg can’t go into a round hole because of the fact that the solid object around it prevents it. Isn’t that prevention a law or no? Even if this isn’t, what about things like gravity?

Comment: This is the issue of debate between Humeans and anti-Humeans. "For Humeans, laws have more of a descriptive character: the laws are (merely) accurate reports of what regularly happens or is universally the case... those who subscribe to some kind of regularity view deny that laws necessitate anything because they usually agree with David Hume that the postulation of necessity in nature is suspect." [PhilPapers](https://philpapers.org/browse/humeanism-and-nonhumeanism-about-laws) Even many anti-Humeans frame it differently, as some dispositions of objects with causal powers inducing the laws.

Comment: No it's not a law, at least not an intangible general principle that preexisted your formulation of it. What you are doing is exactly what @D.Halsey warned you against: you are seeing a regularity that just organically arises from perfectly mundane interactions between material objects and decrees it must be some immaterial law. And then you have this law you created and are embarassed with it's ontological status and you must make up some extravagant theory about immaterial stuff having causal power when there was no need for a law in the first place.

Comment: @Conifold  If they are merely descriptions, doesn’t this mean that there’s no deeper explanation behind why things follow certain regularities in the first place? It seems as if laws being prescriptive would atleast give that explanation

Comment: @armand It seems then that you are stating that regularities are just brute facts then. Why do those interactions between material objects occur in a certain way instead of another? The “mundane interactions between material objects” thus exist without cause and for no reason. If one asks **how** those interactions arise, your answer will thus be “it just happens”, correct? A prescribed law atleast would give a reason for those interactions. I’m not taking a case here and don’t see how one is more fanciful than another yet.

Comment: The same objects interacting in the same way give the same result, yep. It just happens and it makes complete sense. On the other end your taking the description of events for prescriptions forces you to posit some immaterial principle existing out of nowhere for no reason, that would force those objects to interact the way they do. At face value it does not make much more sense, arguably less, to be honest.

Comment: "Brute fact" is used narrowly or broadly. In the narrow sense, it is a fact that calls for explanation but does not have one. For Humeans, regularities do not call for any explanation, they happen to be there just as much as irregularities do, so they are not brute facts either. And generally, if one rejects PSR there is no fact of the matter as to whether something is a brute fact, it depends on one's methodological tastes as to where explanations are called for.

Comment: @armand The same things interacting in the same way gives the same result makes complete sense to me as well. But why do they interact in one way vs. another? And what makes them interact in one way vs. another? I suppose you could argue these questions assume prescriptive laws but I’m not sure.

Comment: I guess the cause of your confusion is included in your very question. By asking "what makes them interact in one way vs. another?" you're already presupposing that there is an entity that *makes* them do something. "why do they interact in one way vs. another" is much more neutral in it's formulation, and i don't think anything outside of the interacting objects has to be posited in order to answer it. But I'll admit it supposes that "objects" can be defined without subjectivity, and probably i'm a bit out of my depth on this one.

Comment: It is an artifact of how we think.

Comment: @thinkingman I'm fully on your train of thought here as well. And if QM has any truth to it, the things we're used to thinking of as 'objects' - namely, atoms and molecules and the like - aren't the fundamental unit of causality in our universe anyway, so saying causality resulting in this reliable descriptions is just a function of objects doing what objects do... doesn't seem to tell the whole story to me. It seems apparent to me that there really is some level of abstract "rules", whether we know what they are or not, that underly the consistent behavior of matter in our world.

Comment: The big problem is **obey**. Nature does not obey human "laws". Nature is not subservient to humans.

Comment: How do you know the laws are only human? @WeatherVane

Answer (score 3):

The laws of nature have no causal power themselves. They are not causes to any effects.

They only describe the relations between causes and their effects.

Comment: Yes, so I think that @thinkingman s question amounts to, "*Ok then, what causes those causes?*" To which, there is no answer. The definition of a cause is that it causes things. Going farther just turns your mind in to a pretzel.

Answer (score 1):

This dialectic can be seen as an example of the difference between truth-conditional and property-conditional semantics. As the SEP article on axiomatic theories of truth [puts it](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/truth-axiomatic/#TrutPropSets):

[image]

So when a law of nature is taken to be determinative, this is as if to say that the truth of sentences reporting these laws is established first, and then the properties (or states) of things are set according to such truth; when a law of nature is not determinative but merely determinate, here, we would read the relation in the other direction.

Another, similar (but *not* the same!) interpretation of the dialectic can be found in the SEP article on "laws of nature," where the determinative conception of laws can be seen as the conception [appealing to universals](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/laws-of-nature/#Uni):

[image]

Of course, neither what we might call the "bottom-up" nor the "top-down"<sup>π</sup> conception has won the day. The just-quoted article concludes:

> How will matters progress? How can philosophy advance beyond the current disputes about laws of nature? Three issues are especially interesting and important ones. The first concerns whether lawhood is a part of the content of scientific theories. This is a question often asked about causation, but less frequently addressed about lawhood. Roberts offers an analogy in support of the thought that it is not: It is a postulate of Euclidean geometry that two points determine a line. But it is not part of the content of Euclidean geometry that this proposition is a postulate. Euclidean geometry is not a theory about postulates; it is a theory about points, lines, and planes … (2008, 92). This may be a plausible first step toward understanding the absence of some nomic terms from formal statements of scientific theories. The second issue is whether there are any contingent laws of nature. Necessitarians continue to work on filling in their view, while Humeans and others pay relatively little attention to what they are up to; new work needs to explain the source of the underlying commitments that divide these camps. Finally, more attention needs to be paid to the language used to report what are the laws and the language used to express the laws themselves and whether the laws explain. It is clear that recent disputes about generalizations in physics and the special sciences turn on precisely these matters, but exploring them may also pay dividends on central matters regarding ontology, realism vs. antirealism, and supervenience.

---

<sup>π</sup>To try to avoid compromising on parsimony too much: does the arrangement of the world-whole's parts determine the world or does the world determine the arrangement of its parts? (Is asserting a world-whole less parsimonious than asserting just the parts?)

Comment: I should clarify that the article on axiomatic theories of truth is not about this dialectic on its (the article's) own terms, but I was applying the theme of the article to the OP question.